# MySQL: count(id) returns 1 instead of actual total rows when using GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

My query is below (it searches for parents and children 4 levels up and down). As this, I get the amount of rows found in a single "num" value: about ~22k rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(fts_trip_id) AS num 
FROM feed_trips_se
JOIN departures ON d_departure_id=fts_trip_departure_id
JOIN destinations ON destinations.d_destination_id=d_departure_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destChild1 ON destChild1.d_destination_parent_id=destinations.d_destination_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destChild2 ON destChild2.d_destination_parent_id=destChild1.d_destination_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destChild3 ON destChild3.d_destination_parent_id=destChild2.d_destination_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destChild4 ON destChild4.d_destination_parent_id=destChild3.d_destination_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destParent1 ON destParent1.d_destination_id=destinations.d_destination_parent_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destParent2 ON destParent2.d_destination_id=destParent1.d_destination_parent_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destParent3 ON destParent3.d_destination_id=destParent2.d_destination_parent_id
LEFT JOIN destinations AS destParent4 ON destParent4.d_destination_id=destParent3.d_destination_parent_id
WHERE fts_trip_date>=NOW()
ORDER BY fts_trip_date ASC, fts_trip_price ASC
```

However, as I'm using lots of LEFT JOINs, the number ~22k isn't the correct amount of trips available. I need to group those rows by the actual fts_trip_id.

Unfortunately, when I do the GROUP BY, instead of getting a single row of the correct number of trips, I get the same amount of rows as the correct number of trips (~8k). All the rows are then displaying a number, most often 1 but also 10 or 13.

I honestly don't know why I don't get the single row value of ~8k when I use the GROUP BY function. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [COUNT(DISTINCT)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct): `COUNT(DISTINCT fts_trip_id)` to get a count of the ids.
GROUP BY will just get counts of the number of results for each id.